# Куки: если возможность вытащить физический ip Адрес

Tags: сеть, ip

Вопрос токой: можно-ли спарсить через куки физический ip Адрес пользователя.

Comment: Кука это просто блок информации, вы сами решаете что в него записать. Браузер лишь вернет вам то, что вы туда сами записали. Если запишите ip то будет там ip. правда ip обратившегося к вам и так обычно без всяких кук видно

Comment: Гм... а что такое "физический IP-адрес"? локальный, что ли? а нафига он нужен, если он в большинстве случаев - серый?

Comment: Вытащить физический адрес посредством куки невозможно.

Comment: А как насчёт возможности спарсить IMEI 1 и 2 далие найти. В слитых БД владельца данного гаджета

Comment: @вадимбакшеев А какое это имеет отношение к кукисам?

Comment: @nick_n_a Так через куки собирать какие-то данные. чтоб потом найти информацию в слитых БД о пользователи его место проживание и так далие имя фамилия  (вообще чисто теоритически это возможно)?

Comment: Куки - во первых - публичные т.е. их (свои куки) может посмотреть почти каждый, во вторых - их обьем лимитирован (один или несколько кб - макс). Поэтому во-первых, ввиду того что из-за куки уже были судебные разбирательства причём в пользу истца, разработчикам нет смысла рисковать, и хранить там личную информацию, при том, что данную информацию можно хранить в другом месте, а во вторых - может не хватить места в кукисах, для хранения такой информации.

Comment: Именно результатом выигрыша истцом в суде являются таблички с предупреждением "я согласен с куки". Поскольку в многих библиотеках авторизации используются куки для идентификации входа - то отказаться от них сайты где нужна регистрация - не могут. Там где регистрация не нужна - возможно не хотят. Поэтому слово куки вы видите часто.

Comment: Куки не используется в 99% случаев для хранения личной инфы (разве что кем-то недобросовесным кто не боится законов). В большинстве случаев куки - это номер "билета", либо "подписаный" номер билета + дата. По номеру - сайт может понять был данный пользователь на даном (или подчинённом) сайте или нет. А личная инормация хранится в базе фирмы, часто защищена несколькими защитами от взлома. Всё.